# yii2 : dynamic dosamigos HighCharts from database

Tags: highcharts, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I need to generate a dynamic Highcharts  get the data from database , so i tried to follow the example here :

https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget

in My Controller :

```
public function actionReports()
{
   $data= User::find()
        ->select(['COUNT(*) AS count,gender '])
        ->groupBy(['gender'])
        ->all();
    return $this->render('reports',[
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

in my View :

```
<?php 
use dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts;



      foreach ($data  as $user) {
          $gender= "['name'=>'".$user->gender."','data'=>[".$user->count."]],";
          print_r($gender);
       }
 echo \dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts::widget([
'clientOptions' => [
    'chart' => [
            'type' => 'bar'
    ],
    'title' => [
         'text' => 'By Gender'
         ],

    'yAxis' => [
        'title' => [
            'text' => 'Genders'
        ]
    ],
    'series' =>[ $gender,]
]
 ]);
?>
```

but after that there is something wrong because No charts appears ,
But In
    `$gender` 
there is data as it has to be to make the charts work :

> ['name'=>'female','data'=>[1]],['name'=>'male','data'=>[4]],

`

Comment: you are not providing the data correctly what kind of a graph are you expecting to be drawn as looking at your current code there isnt going to be any bars shown as there isnt any `xAxis` provided neither there isnt any third entity to draw the bars against, please see the examples

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Do you know if I replaced `$gender` with this data `['name'=>'female','data'=>[1]],['name'=>'male','data'=>[4]],` its works fine and its draw the graphs , and this data = `$gender`

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Comment: Hi @Naeem Ali, Could you provide us with a generated JS code?

Comment: @ppotaczek I don't get what I should share with you !

Comment: I do not know PHP well, but this problem looks similar to asynchrony problem in JS - static data works, but not dynamic. Is it possible that the data is not yet loaded when creating the chart?

Comment: @ppotaczek its my problem that static data works fine with me but the dynamic is not .

Comment: @Naeem Ali - Could you add to your question a part of your code where you get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highchart require data as integer but active record returns it as string. We have to type cast data to integer.

```
$data = User::find()
    ->select(['COUNT(*) AS count,gender'])
    ->groupBy('gender')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

foreach ($data  as $user) {
    $gender[] = ['name' => $user['gender'], 'data' => [(int) $user['count']]];
}

echo HighCharts::widget([
    'clientOptions' => [
        'chart' => [
            'type' => 'bar',
        ],
        'title' => [
            'text' => 'By Gender',
        ],
        'yAxis' => [
            'title' => [
               'text' => 'Genders',
            ],
        ],
        'series' => $gender
    ],
]);
```